# Connection refused with Modbus TCP using Telegraf and InfluxDB

Tags: plugins, influxdb, modbus, plc, telegraf

I am trying to use Telegraf for first time. I have PLC with working modbus TCP on it (checked with other tools) and InfluxDB on my Raspberry Pi.

Please help me figure out **what exactly is not working?**

I attach Telegraf config and log

When checking Telegraf config with

```
telegraf -config telegraf.conf -input-filter modbus -test
```

I get:

```
2020-11-16T12:17:56Z I! Starting Telegraf 1.16.2
2020-11-16T12:17:56Z E! [inputs.modbus] Error in plugin: dial tcp [::1]:502: connect: connection refused
2020-11-16T12:17:56Z E! [telegraf] Error running agent: input plugins recorded 1 errors
```

I have already spend a day on it, I guess it is something obvious that i am missing.

Please help,
best regards,
Darek

Here is telegraf.log:
[telegraf.log](https://pastebin.pl/view/9af0f488)

Here is Telegraf config:
[Telegraf config file](https://pastebin.pl/view/3b608ba5)

Edit:
the problem was that I did not launch telegraf with my telegraf.comf configuration file. The configuration file has to be pointed directly, like:

C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /k C:\Users\myUser\SCADA\telegraf-1.20.3\telegraf.exe --config C:\Users\myUser\SCADA\telegraf-1.20.3\telegraf.conf

Comment: The log you have pasted does not match the error in your question (error in log is `dial tcp 169.254.230.136:502: connect: network is unreachable`). The IP `169.254.230.136` (in config and log) is a [link-local address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link-local_address) and `::1` is [loopback](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loopback) so this looks like an issue with your network setup. Ensure you can access your PLC with something like [mbpoll](https://github.com/epsilonrt/mbpoll) before trying Telegraf.

Comment: Thank you Brits,
took a while since I can face the problem again.

I changed to static IP for RPI and PLC under local router network. I now have 192.168.0.101 for PLC. I Successfully read PLC modbus registers with mbpoll, but still the same error from telegraf.

Is it possible, that telegraf starts numbering registers from 1 and PLC expects numbering from 0? With mbpoll PLC answers only if mbpoll numbers from 0. Is is possible to change numbering in telegraf?

Comment: Or maybe telegraf ignores that I set PLC IP in telegraf.conf to 192.168.0.101 and for some reason telegraf polls the raspberry instead polling PLC? 
And that is the reason for "connection refused" since no modbus server is running on raspberry...?

Comment: Please update your question with the relevant details (current error message, config etc).

Answer (score 0):

The reason of not working was too obvious to notice for me. My telegraf instance simply did not use telegraf.conf. It actually used one telegraf.conf, but not the one which I thought so (not the one which I was editing).

Now I explicitly point the configuration file for telegraf, when I launch it.
I have desktop shortcut with command like this:

```
C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /k C:\Users\myUser\SCADA\telegraf-1.20.3\telegraf.exe --config C:\Users\myUser\SCADA\telegraf-1.20.3\telegraf.conf
```